# How to use composite primary key in trigger (Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have created the following table

create table tab(id NUMBER, val VARCHAR2(50), last_date DATE, PRIMARY KEY(id,val))

And I am using the following PL/SQL block for creating trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIG AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tab 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE
           l_enqueue_options DBMS_AQ.enqueue_options_t;
           l_message_properties DBMS_AQ.message_properties_t;
           l_txn_event_msg tab_PAYLOAD;
           l_message_handle RAW(16);
           ERR_MSG VARCHAR2(600);
           primaryKey VARCHAR2(4000);
           opnCode VARCHAR2(10);
    BEGIN
           IF INSERTING THEN
               opnCode := 'INSERT';
               primaryKey := :new.id;
           ELSIF UPDATING THEN
               opnCode := 'UPDATE';
               primaryKey := :new.id;
           ELSIF DELETING THEN
               opnCode := 'DELETE';
               primaryKey := :old.id;
           END IF;

           l_txn_event_msg := tab_PAYLOAD(
                primaryKey, opnCode, sysdate,:new.id,'DUMMY'
           );

           DBMS_AQ.enqueue(
              queue_name => 'tab_Q',
              enqueue_options => l_enqueue_options,
              message_properties => l_message_properties,
              payload => l_txn_event_msg,
              msgid => l_message_handle
           );

      EXCEPTION
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
           WHEN OTHERS THEN
                ERR_MSG := sqlerrm || ' Error while executing trigger TRIG_UB.';
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Some exception occured in tab ==>' || ERR_MSG);
      END;
```

Now is the above trigger correct ? I want to use composite primary keys in the trigger , something like this primaryKey := :new.id|||||old.id; Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: a clob in a primary key... I never thought at that...

Comment: Does your trigger compile? What is the error?